# Why do we say that one is obligated to follow his family minhag?

Tags: minhag, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

I understand that there is an obligation to follow ‘minhag hamakom’ sourced in Gemara Pesachim 50b. However I am perplexed as to why we say one is obligated to follow his family minhag (for example Ashkenazim not eating kitniyot on Pesach).

I have heard that the source for this is the verse in Mishlei 1:8 “שמע בני מוסר אביך ואל תטש ,תורת אמך”. However this seems to be an incorrect exposition of this verse. The various times it is quoted in Shas, it is only in reference to minhag hamakom (see Rashi on Chulin 93b, Pesachim 50b). If someone could enlighten me, that would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Who said you are? If an ashkenazi wants to join a local sefardi community what's the problem? People have done that forever. The only problem is potentially people who want to pick and choose from multiple communities so they don't end up belonging to any. There were always places that had multiple communities and you clearly have to belong to one

Comment: @DoubleAA - what is the issue with picking and choosing?

Comment: @Tesvov Agreed. Why would there be an issue with picking and choosing? They are individual minhagim and if you say that there is no halachik obligation to follow family minhag, then you should be able to pick and choose. It is important to note that while historically an Ashkenazi minhag would have been minhag hamakom (e.g. in Ashkenaz), that’s simply untrue nowadays where we live in mixed communities.

Comment: I invite both of you to reread my comment

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the point you’re trying to make then. Could you please explain what you meant?

Comment: You'll get lost

Comment: see [The Legal Thinking of the Tosafot: A Historical Approach (by Hakham José Faur)](https://www.scribd.com/document/60646260/Untitled)